# Can not deploy async Firebase function

Tags: javascript, firebase, async-await, firebase-authentication

I am trying to add a user role with the following function. The function should be deployed as firebase function.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')

admin.initializeApp()
const db = admin.firestore()

exports.AddUserRole = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (authUser) => {
  if (authUser.email) {
    const customClaims = {
      admin: true,
    }
    try {
      let _ = await admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(authUser.uid, customClaims)
      return db.collection('roles').doc(authUser.uid).set({
        email: authUser.email,
        role: customClaims,
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
})
```

When I try to deploy with firebase deploy --only functions:AddUserRole it I get an **error Parsing error: Unexpected token =>** and the deployment fails.

If I remove the async/await it works just fine but I need the async await for this and future functions so I would like to know what I am doing wrong.

Some additional information. I am using node v.12.21.0 and the latest versions of all firebase tools / SDK etc.

Comment: Are you sure Firebase supports the version of ECMAScript needed for async/await?

Comment: I have people seen use async/await in firease functions. So yea

Comment: does `async function (authUser) {` work?

Comment: Already tried it. I get the same error just with function

Comment: @MarcelKlein Were you able to resolve this issue? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could remove the '_ = ...' and await the response of setting the new document in roles and return that instead.

It's just a suggestion but I hope it helps.

```
exports.AddUserRole = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (authUser) => {
  if (authUser.email) {
    const customClaims = {
      admin: true,
    }
  try {
    await admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(authUser.uid, customClaims)
    //Or whatever you want to call it
    const updatedRole = await db.collection('roles').doc(authUser.uid).set({
      email: authUser.email,
      role: customClaims,
    })
      return updatedRole
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your response I will certainly take this into consideration but this is not solving my issue.